# Is there a way to see a more verbose output from Clang?

Tags: clang

I would like to see a more verbose output from `clang`, more than it produces when run as `clang -v`.

So far I tried: `clang --help`, `clang --help-hidden` and `clang -cc1 --help` but didn't find anything that would help.

I am particularly interested in whether I can see the traces of a reasoning that `clang` does to decide on if it has to recompile a particular .cpp file.

Comment: clang doesn't make decisions as to whether to recompile a file.  If you tell it to build something, it builds it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you will add "-###" at the end of your command.
For example:

```
clang -c main.c -o main -###
```